# mathematical function for this curve

Tags: expected-value, curves, parametric, boundary-value-problem

I need to find a mathematical function that looks like this curve:

Please look at this picture:

[image: draft of the curve]

1. $f_{max}(x)= 10$
2. $f(x_{end}) = 5$
3. $f(0) = 0$

I already have this function:

$f(x) = a*x^2*e^{b*x^2}+c$

But this function has an asymptote that goes to 0:

$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}\rightarrow 0$

But my goal is, that the function has a finite final value that is greater than 0 and is not an asymptote. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you define it by parts? first on two different intervals?

Comment: @Martingalo , what that can be a befitting answer for this question is a piecewise function, right ?

Comment: Yes, for instance, a piecewise defined function on $[0,20]$ and then on $(20,\infty)$ where they match in a $C^1$ way for example.

Comment: it actually needs to be a continuous function

Comment: It can be continuous even though it is piecewise

Comment: and how? i cant define it by parts. it has to be a single line formula to use in matlab

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You can try this function $f(x) = \frac{Ax^2 + Bx +C}{Dx^2+Ex+F}$.

Condition $f(x)=0$ implies that $C=0$. Hence, $f(x) = \frac{Ax^2 + Bx}{Dx^2+Ex+F}$.

Condition $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=5$ implies that $A=5D$. We can also choose $D=1$ for simplicity now, but you can pick $D$ at your convenience. Then
$$f(x)=\frac{5x^2 + Bx}{x^2+Ex+F}.$$

It remains to impose that $f'(a)=0$ at some point $x=a$ and $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in [0,a)$ and $f'(x)<0$ for all $x\in (a,\infty)$. Also, $f(a)=10$.

First, $f(a)=\frac{5a^2 + Ba}{a^2+Ea+F}=10$ implies $10a^2 + (10E-B)a + 10F=0$.

Also,
$$f'(x) = \frac{(5E-B)x^2+10Fx+BF}{(x^2+Ex+F)^2}.$$
The critical points are:
$$x_{crit}= \frac{-10F \pm \sqrt{100F^2-4BF(5E-B)}}{2(5E-B)}.$$
So, you need $100F^2 > 4BF(5E-B)$ and then $a$ is the positive root.

I think in particular if you choose $B>E$ and $a=\frac{-10F - \sqrt{100F^2-4BF(5E-B)}}{2(5E-B)}$ you get one possible choice.

For example, $A=5$, $B=2$, $C=0$, $D=1$, $E=1$ and $F$ as you want.
$$f(x)=\frac{5x^2 + 2x }{x^2+x+F}$$
you get a function with your properties. Another question is if you can tune the parameters $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$ and $F$ to make the function have more prominent maximum and decreasing shape towards $y=5$.

**2)** So, another choice is to simply take:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} Ax^2+Bx+C, \quad x\in [0,k),\\
D, \quad x\in [k,\infty),
\end{cases}
$$
for some constants $A$, $B$, $C$ and $k$.

If $A<0$ then the function $f(x) = Ax^2+Bx$ is a family of concave parabolas passing through the points $(0,0)$ and $(-\frac{B}{A},0)$ and its maximum is at point $(-\frac{B}{2A},-\frac{B^2}{4A})$. Since $-\frac{B^2}{4A}=10$ we have $B^2 = -40A$. Now, you want a line on $y=5$. The intersection of $y=5$ with the parabola are the two points: $x_{1,2} = \frac{-B\pm \sqrt{B^2 - 20A}}{2A}$. The right point is
$$k=\frac{-B- \sqrt{B^2 - 20A}}{2A}$$
and you can thus define

$$f_{A,B}(x) = \begin{cases} Ax^2+Bx, \quad x\in [0,k),\\
5, \quad x\in [k,\infty),
\end{cases}$$

where

$$k=\frac{-B- \sqrt{B^2 - 20A}}{2A}$$
for all $A$ and $B$ such that $A<0$ and $-\frac{B^2}{4A}=10$.

The family of functions $f_{A,B}$ have a maximum at $x=a=-\frac{B}{A}$ and such that $f_{A,B}(a)=10$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f_{A,B}(x)=5$.

$$$$

Comment: thank you so much for your work! Sadly the function f(x)=5x^2+2x/x^2+x+F does not give me the right shape of the function for F>0, as the final value is not smaller than the maximum value. For F<0 the shape of the function is just odd. Also i dont quite understand the second half of your answer. I dont know why there is suddenly 2a as the point of the maximum. Can you please give me an example which has the right shape?

Comment: The fact that I chose $2a$ was just random, just to place the maximum in the middle. If $x=a$ then the interval $[0,2a]$ has the value $a$ in the middle. But you can choose an arbitraty interval $[0,k]$ where $k$ should be such that $Ak^2 +Bk\geq 5$ so that the shape of the function is similar to your plot.

Comment: if i calculate A and B with $B^2=40*A$ and $Ak^2+Bk=5$ for k =1 and then compute the curve for A, B, $C=0$, $D=5$ and $F=1$ the final value is aprox -28 and not 5. I dont know what i am doing wrong

Comment: I tried to be more concise now, check option 2 in my answer again and try some values of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: unfortunately it still does not work. for $k=2$ and i get $A\approx -12$ and $B\approx 22$. With $C=0$,$D=1$,$E=1$ and $F=1$ the curve still does not got to $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \rightarrow 5$. instead it goes to $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \rightarrow -12.75$. Can you please give me some example values for A and B?

Comment: I meant the piecewise function. (for example: if you try $A=-40$ $B=40$ then $k\approx 0.8535$ and $a=0.5$)
For a unified function you may have to investigate other options, but using piecewise functions you have many possibilities. Another possibility is a parabola and $f(x)=\frac{A}{x}+5$ on the left such that they match continuously. There are infinitely many choices :)

Comment: I actually dont understand what you mean... can you please just help me modify $f=\frac{A*x^2+B*x}{x^2+x+F}$ so that it meets the boundary conditions? It definitely must not be a piecewise function

Comment: I think $f(x) = \frac{5x^3+Ax^2+Bx}{x^3+Cx^2+Dx+E}$ is a better choice, but finding the exact suitable family of functions may be algebraically difficult.

Comment: thank you for your patience so far. Unfortunately this function doesnt work either. I just need one simple function that just looks similar to my draft function....